# How to filter same requests using Laravel

Tags: laravel, real-time

My code is

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $invite = Invite::where('hash', $request->input('invite_token'))->first();

    if($invite->status != 'sent')
        return;

    $invite->update([
        'status' => 'creating_test_instance'
    ]);

    event(new CreatingTestInstance($invite));

    $createTestInstanceJob = new CreateTestInstance($invite);

    dispatch($createTestInstanceJob);
}
```

If i'll send simultaneously several same requests the first request cannot get in time to update status and

`if($invite->status != 'sent')
            return;`

not being applied and Test instance is being created multiple times.
I can have only one Test instance on one invite.
How could it be protected?
Implemented it with database transaction but if you have any better solution very glad to hear.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: If you send the requests simultaneously there is going to be conflict issues. Can you not control how many requests are sent and control the conflict that way?

Comment: I've tested sending ten requests simultaneously, three of them passed check.

Comment: Why would there be ten requests for the same invite?

Comment: Because there is a possibility that i have to prevent.It could be sent ten requests.So I have to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$invite->update([
    'status' => 'creating_test_instance'
]);
```

With:

```
$invite->status = 'creating_test_instance';
$invite->save();
```

See if it makes any difference

Comment: That won't help,  because this is almost the same behavior.Maybe will help in other situations, but not here.